# How to put ownCloud behind Nginx with Docker?

Tags: nginx, docker, owncloud

I want to access an ownCloud instance trough Nginx both set up inside separate Docker containers. So I've made `docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  links:
    - owncloud
owncloud:
  image: owncloud
  ports:
    - 6789:80
  volumes:
    - ~/ownCloud:/var/www/html/data
```

And `nginx.conf` to proxify requests with following contents:

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name docker.dev;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6789;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
  }
}
events {}
```

Seems right to me, but Nginx logs out such message:

`[error] 6#6: *8 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: docker.dev`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you verify owncloud is up and receiving connections independent of Nginx (i.e. hit it directly at port 6789)?

Comment: @Eli yeah it works when I'm hitting `docker.dev:6789`

Comment: Problem could be you're hitting 127.0.0.1 through nginx when you should be hitting docker.dev. Can you try changing the `proxy_pass` line to `proxy_pass http://docker.dev:6789`?

Comment: @Eli didn't worked, probably 'cause `*.dev` zone is provided by dnsmasq on local machine and only points to `$DOCKER_HOST` ip

Comment: @Eli also Nginx interprets `docker.dev` as an upstream which doesn't exist in my `nginx.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside the nginx container, `127.0.0.1:6789` will not map to owncloud. This is because, docker is only mapping port `80` on owncloud port `6789` on the host machine.

Imagine each container as well as the docker host is a completely separate machine. In this case the nginx machine sends a request to `127.0.0.1` which is just itself, not the host machine, not the owncloud machine.

There are many ways to communicate between docker containers and you are already using one of them, docker compose's built in [linking system](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links).

In your `docker-compose.yml` you have already linked owncloud to nginx, which is correct. What this does is edit the nginx containers `/etc/hosts` file to map `owncloud` the owncloud container's ip address. (You can check it out by running `docker exec name_of_nginx_container cat /etc/hosts`). What this means is, inside the nginx container `http://owncloud` maps to port `80` on the owncloud comtainer.

With that in mind, this is a full configuration that works with docker compose's linking system.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  ports:
    - 80:80
  volumes:
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  links:
    - owncloud
owncloud:
  image: owncloud
  expose:
    - 80
  volumes:
    - ~/ownCloud:/var/www/html/data
```

`nginx.conf`

```
http {
  server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name docker.dev;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://owncloud;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
  }
}
events {}
```

The only differences are that you only need to expose port `80` on the owncloud image, not map it to the host and the `proxy_pass` line in `nginx.conf`.

Hope that helps.